# Casting a number to a string in TypeScript

Tags: javascript, casting, typescript

Which is the the best way (if there is one) to cast from number to string in Typescript?

```
var page_number:number = 3;
window.location.hash = page_number;
```

In this case the compiler throws the error:

> Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'string'

Because `location.hash` is a string.

```
window.location.hash = ""+page_number; //casting using "" literal
window.location.hash = String(number); //casting creating using the String() function
```

So which method is better?

Answer (score 450, accepted):

"Casting" is different than conversion. In this case, `window.location.hash` will auto-convert a number to a string. But to avoid a TypeScript compile error, you can do the string conversion yourself:

```
window.location.hash = ""+page_number; 
window.location.hash = String(page_number);
```

These conversions are ideal if you don't want an error to be thrown when `page_number` is `null` or `undefined`. Whereas `page_number.toString()` and `page_number.toLocaleString()` will throw when `page_number` is `null` or `undefined`.

When you only need to cast, not convert, this is how to cast to a string in TypeScript:

```
window.location.hash = <string>page_number; 
// or 
window.location.hash = page_number as string;
```

The `<string>` or `as string` cast annotations tell the TypeScript compiler to treat `page_number` as a string at compile time; it doesn't convert at run time.

However, the compiler will complain that you can't assign a number to a string. You would have to first cast to `<any>`, then to `<string>`:

```
window.location.hash = <string><any>page_number;
// or
window.location.hash = page_number as any as string;
```

So it's easier to just convert, which handles the type at run time and compile time:

```
window.location.hash = String(page_number);
```

(Thanks to @RuslanPolutsygan for catching the string-number casting issue.)

Comment: Careful, if `page_number` is `null` this will set `window.location.hash` to *the string `"null"`. (I'd prefer an error :D).

Comment: If you don't want compiler to complain just say `window.location.hash = <any>page_number;`

Comment: Using **conversion** (ie. `String(page_number)`) rather than *casting* is necessary when you want to use any `String` methods, like `toLowerCase()`.

Comment: Also, you can use template string `\`${page_number}\``

Answer (score 42):

Utilize [`toString()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toString) (or [`toLocaleString()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toLocaleString), but take care that it might add things like 1000's separator characters), for example:

```
var page_number:number = 3;
window.location.hash = page_number.toString();
```

---

These throw an error if `page_number` is `null` or `undefined`. If you don't want that you can choose the fix appropriate for your situation:

```
// Fix 1:
window.location.hash = (page_number || 1).toString();

// Fix 2a:
window.location.hash = !page_number ? "1" page_number.toString();

// Fix 2b (allows page_number to be zero):
window.location.hash = (page_number !== 0 && !page_number) ? "1" page_number.toString();

// Fix 3, modern js:
window.location.hash = page_number?.toString() || "1";
```

Comment: Do not use toLocaleString for large numbers as it adds commas just like a currency. It will destroy identifiers.

Comment: I had missed the above comment at the time, but it's very valid and have slipstreamed that info into the answer.

Answer (score 16):

One can also use the following syntax in typescript. Note the backtick " ` "

```
window.location.hash = `${page_number}`
```

Comment: It is a javascript feature, not a typescript one. I think it is cleaner to just use String(page_number)

Comment: FWIW Typescript HAS overloaded this syntax with template types

Answer (score 12):

This is some short ways

```
any_type = "" + any_type; 
any_type = String(any_type); 
any_type = `${any_type}`;
```

Answer (score 7):

window.location.hash is a `string`, so do this:

```
var page_number: number = 3;
window.location.hash = String(page_number);
```

Answer (score 4):

Easiest way:

`` var num = 3; var str =`${num}`; ``

Answer (score 3):

Just use: `page_number?.toString()`

Answer (score 0):

> const page_number = 3;
>
> window.location.hash = page_number as string; // Error

"Conversion of type 'number' to type 'string' may be a mistake because neither type sufficiently overlaps with the other. If this was intentional, convert the expression to 'unknown' first." -> You will get this error if you try to typecast number to string. So, first convert it to unknown and then to string.

> window.location.hash = (page_number as unknown) as string; // Correct way