# Why error is appear during execution only in second case?

Tags: typescript

What is the problem with the second situation?

```
function f(x) {   
    return (x as string).toLocaleUpperCase();
}

console.log("hello: "+ f("mr.")); // hello: MR.
console.log("hello: "+ f(0));
```

> Uncaught TypeError: x.toLocaleUpperCase is not a function
>      at f (:2:14)
>      at :5:25
>      at HTMLButtonElement.excuteButton.onclick >(https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/playground.js:247)

Comment: console.log("hello: "+ f("mr.")); // hello: MR.                                  
console.log("hello: "+ f(0)); // Uncaught TypeError: x.toLocaleUpperCase is not a 
                                            //function

Comment: 0 is not a string, it doesn't have `toLocaleUpperCase` function.

Comment: `(x + '' as string)` solves it, because you add a string to your variable, thus turning the number into a `string` (only `strings` have the toUpperCase functions)

Comment: I suspect you're missing tags - `x as string` seems like TypeScript.

Comment: Have a read of this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32554624/casting-a-number-to-a-string-in-typescript

Answer (score 0):

from what I understand, your typescript code is transcribed into the following javascript code:

```
function f(x) {
    return x.toLocaleUpperCase();
}
console.log("hello: " + f("mr.")); // hello: MR.
console.log("hello: " + f(0));
```

And since numbers (like 0), don't have a `toLocalUpperCase` field, you get an error.

I'm not sure if this is the most typescript-ish way to do it, but here's an alternative that works for both your cases:

```
function f(x) {   
    return x.toString().toLocaleUpperCase();
}

console.log("hello: "+ f("mr.")); // hello: MR.
console.log("hello: "+ f(0));
```